# unit testing Mail::send()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Say I'm sending an email with `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::send()`. How would I test this to see if an email had in fact been sent?

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking#mail-fake mentions `Mail::assertSent()` but that requires you a pass to it a `@param string $mailable` variable and idk what that variable would need to be with `Mail::send()`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably create a mailable using `artisan make:mail` command. Simply pass to assertSent class name of that mail.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to call `Mail::fake()` while testing, and `Mail::send()` when in production. That should be part of your testing facade.

Even if you your code claims the mail was sent, you'll may want to go a step further and verify the mail was actually received. This will require access to the destination mail server (hard!) ... *or you could use something more public like [Dispostable](https://www.dispostable.com/).*